# Effect of adjusting Y component in YUV?

Tags: c, colors, rgb, yuv

I've been reverse engineering a program and recently came across a function that is intended to create a sort of translucent-looking color to be used for text selections. It does this by converting RGB to YUV, alters the Y (luma?) component, then converts back to RGB.

```
uint32_t CalcSelectionColor(uint32_t bgr)
{
  double r,g,b;
  double y,u,v;

  r = (bgr >>  0) & 0xFF;
  g = (bgr >>  8) & 0xFF;
  b = (bgr >> 16) & 0xFF;

  /* RGB to YUV */
  y = 0.299*r + 0.587*g + 0.114*b;
  u = (b-y) * 0.565 * 0.5;
  v = (r-y) * 0.713 * 0.5;

  /* lower brightness? */
  y = 255.0 - y;

  /* YUV to RGB */
  r = y + 1.403*v;
  g = y - 0.344*u - 0.714*v;
  b = y + 1.77*u;

  return ((uint8_t)(b) << 16) | ((uint8_t)(g) << 8) | ((uint8_t)(r));
}
```

As someone with very limited knowledge of computer graphics, I'd just like a bit more detail of what it does between the conversions, and the actually intended effect in a broader sense. Is this a common approach of adjusting brightness of a color or something? If I pass in 0x00FF00, the result I get is 0x1E9D1E

Comment: Y is brightness. You can probably figure out the rest yourself.

Comment: Take any graphic program, check the color picker, and try to get a sense of the various parameters. Note: it doesn't lowe the brightness, it inverts it (e.g. dark on a light colour)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The formulas used in this code are similar to Julien transformation from RGB to YUV and back:

```
Transformation from RGB to YUV:

   Y = 0.299R + 0.587G + 0.114B
   U'= (B-Y)*0.565
   V'= (R-Y)*0.713

Transformation from YUV to RGB:

   R = Y + 1.403V'
   G = Y - 0.344U' - 0.714V'
   B = Y + 1.770U'
```

However, the formulas in your code are a bit different. While the back transformation is the same, the forward transform has an additional multiplier 0.5 for both U and V components. There is also a trivial manipulation with the brightness component

```
y = 255.0 - y
```

which simply inverses the brightness. So, what happens here?

If you use normal Julien RGB->YUV transform, you get a representation for your color as a combination of brightness Y and two color tone components U and V, which define the color as shown on this picture:

[image: UV color plane]

However, in your code you also multiply both U and V components by 0.5. This means, that on this UV plane you move from any given color two times closer to the point of origin (0, 0). For example, if the initial color was A with UV coordinates (-0.4, 0.3), then you'll get a new color B with UV coordinates (-0.2, 0.15). Similarly, the color C (0.2, -0.3) becomes color D (0.1, -0.15):

[image: UV color change]

After that you inverse the brightness of the color, making dark colors bright and bright colors dark. This is the effect of your code.

Comment: Thank you so much for the detailed answer! I feel somewhat enlightened (pun intended). I had my doubts about the multiplication of 0.5 as well, because I never saw it in any other forward transformation before. However, in some sample code for OpenCL (see [RegionGrowingSegmentation.cpp](http://wiapp.cz/debian-live/chroot/opt/AMDAPPSDK-3.0/samples/opencl/cl/2.0/RegionGrowingSegmentation/RegionGrowingSegmentation.cpp)) written by AMD, they **add** 0.5 to U and V instead of multiplying.

Answer (score 2):

It's not terribly common, but it's a very good approach. Commonly used models like HSL/HSV don't represent intensity correctly and have some weird piecewise-linear stuff with hue/color going on. YUV is a really good colorspace, representing intensity along one axis and chroma (hue/color) in a perpendicular plane.

Normally modifying Y without also adjusting (at least clamping) U and V is somewhat dubious, because near the extremes (Y=0 black, Y=full white) U and V have limited range (no range at all at the endpoints). Otherwise applying them will take you outside of the RGB cube and result in bogus clipped results when you go back to RGB. But here the trick is very clever. The code is *inverting* Y while keeping chroma fixed, so the incoming range limits on U and V near black will automatically ensure they're roughly correct in the output, and vice versa.

As Alex noted, the code here is also halving the chroma values, reducing color saturation. This was probably to avoid the above mentioned clipping issue, but it's not needed. But maybe it's part of the intended visual effect too.

So, TL;DR: the effect is inverting intensity/luma and halving saturation.

Comment: Actually the chroma is changed, see my answer.

Comment: @Alex: Thanks. Updated.